# Scrapy only returned 1 item, my brain STUCK

Tags: python, scrapy

here's the spider.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from dts.items import DtItem

class dtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dts'
    urls = ['s','s','s','s']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        for title in response.xpath('//h2/a/@title').extract()[:-6]:
            url_array = response.url.split('/')
            author = url_array[url_array.index('author')+1]
            l = ItemLoader(item=DtItem(), response=response)
            l.add_value('title',title)
            l.add_value('author',author)
            return l.load_item()
```

I wrote this to get the titles only.
But, why can't I get all the titles? **Scrapy only returned 1 item per page.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
return l.load_item()
```

to:

```
yield l.load_item()
```

`return` will stop the function, but `yield` will continue to run.

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks a billion!